# Model selection in linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, model-selection, linear

I got some homework feedback recently, and I don't understand what I did wrong.

I had to select 2,5 and 7 feature models, and couldn't perform stepwise regression (since it had to be done using PySpark, and I didn't see an implementation for that at the time).

I ended up constructing these models using Pearson's correlation (i.e. a model with the 2, 5 and 7 most correlated with the target variable).

These are my results:

```
//The features were normalized prior to constructing the model, but 
the target variable was not.

2:
Explained variance: 1198100424.86
Mean Absolute Error: 5596.52622937
Mean Squared Error: 243471938.055
Root Mean Squared Error: 15603.5873457
R^2: 0.831111138209

5:
Explained variance: 1193222675.73
Mean Absolute Error: 5830.54480402
Mean Squared Error: 245313823.722
Root Mean Squared Error: 15662.4973654
R^2: 0.82983347978

7: 
Explained variance: 1191909326.29
Mean Absolute Error: 5915.68243845
Mean Squared Error: 242263942.387
Root Mean Squared Error: 15564.8303038
R^2: 0.831949086989
```

cross validation was not a requirement here - since it's not a project but just a simple HW assignment (to practice ML models in PySpark).

We were asked to compare the models - in my opinion, there's no real difference between these models. If I'd had to choose one I would choose the one with the 2 features since it has less complexity.

However, I was told that it's common practice to choose a metric and "run" with it even if the differences are minuscule.

Additionally, I was told that I had to add a discussion in my HW regarding the fact the MSE gets bigger the more variables I add.

Am I wrong for thinking these models perform the same? Is the MSE really that different between the models that it requires special attention?

Comment: I would add a selfstudy tag here

Comment: The assignment is based on a usually false premise that feature selection is a good idea.  Model specification is a better one.  And you are ignoring a vast literature on the damage caused by stepwise methods.

Comment: @YuvalSp Tag added.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thank you for the info, I will definitely look into that. However that doesn't answer this particular question.

Comment: True but IMHO it answers a more important one you should not overlook before proceeding.